# Export text file once item is approved

Tags: list, workflow

Is it possible to export a .txt file once the item is approved? I'm doing it using a VBA code on the excel file. This code refresh the excel automatically and export each row to a new .txt file.

Is it possible to do this using workflows? This method above is not really good.

Thank you all!

Comment: What environment are you using?  Is this on-premises or SharePoint Online?  If it's Online, have you considered using Microsoft Flow to handle the approval, and to create the text file you need in a SharePoint document library once the approval succeeds?

Comment: Online, then as Mike says Flows are the way forward. If on premise, then write a custom workflow or try to find codeplex workflow actions.

Comment: Is it possible to edit a sharepoint designer workflow with custom code? How can I do this? I'm using sharepoint on premises